# Sort a list of dictionary based on dictionary key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key

I have a list of python dictionary as follows:

```
[{'k':{'fruit':'apple','flower':'lily'}},
 {'a':{'fruit':'mango','flower':'lotus'}},
 {'e':{'fruit':'peach','flower':'rose'}}]
```

I want to sort the list based on the dictionary key in the following format.

```
[{'a':{'fruit':'mango','flower':'lotus'}},
 {'e':{'fruit':'peach','flower':'rose'}},
 {'k':{'fruit':'apple','flower':'lily'}}]
```

How can I achieve this.Please suggest me.

Comment: Are you sure a dictionary is the right structure in this example?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) (to sort in-place) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (to get a new sorted list) with `key` parameter:

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'k': {'fruit': 'apple', 'flower': 'lily'}},
...     {'a': {'fruit': 'mango', 'flower': 'lotus'}},
...     {'e': {'fruit': 'peach', 'flower': 'rose'}}
... ]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda d: next(iter(d)))
>>> lst
[{'a': {'fruit': 'mango', 'flower': 'lotus'}},
 {'e': {'fruit': 'peach', 'flower': 'rose'}},
 {'k': {'fruit': 'apple', 'flower': 'lily'}}]
```

Comment: `lambda` express can also be written: `lst.sort(key=lambda d: d.items()[0][0])`

Comment: @Hooting, 1. It will not work in Python 3.x where `dict.items` returns an iterator, not a list.  2. Why not `list(d.keys())[0]` or `list(d)[0]`?, only a key is needed, not a value.